# List the elements that appeared in both list?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, binary-search-tree

Given two sorted arrays(without duplicates of course), is there a way to find out and print all the elements that appeared in both arrays?

I know if could get by iterating through one array and build a hashtable, and then iterate the other array and lookup the built table. But that would requires a space of O(n).

I'm trying to see if there is such a way that requires constant additional space, and only requires iterating of each array no more than once. Is it possible?

Now if the above question is possible, if the two sorted list are stored in two binary search trees, is the same approach still applicable given the complicity restriction?

Answer (score 2):

For arrays, do the equivalent of a merge operation, but with no output. During the merge process, any duplicates will be detected. This will involve only one pass per list, and will terminate as soon as the end of either list is reached.

A binary search tree can be traversed iteratively using a stack, but the worst case stack space is O(n). A Morris traversal (do a web search) can traverse a binary tree without using a stack and with O(n) time complexity by changing and restoring the links in the tree (most nodes will be visited multiple times each, but time overhead of multiples of n is still time complexity O(n)). A typical Morris traversal function operates on an entire tree. This will need to be changed so that it returns with each node in order so that merge like logic can be used to check for duplicates. I wrote some test code for this so I can help in case you get stuck.

When traversing a binary tree in order, each current node has a predecessor node, a node that occurs in order just before the current node. The predecessor node will have a null "right" pointer. During a Morris traversal, each predecessor node's "right" pointer is changed from null to point to it's successor node. Eventually when a predecessor node is reached, it's right pointer is followed to reach its successor node, and then the successor node's predecessor node's right pointer is restored back to null.

Since it's been 2 days, here is example code for a Morris traversal function that returns with a pointer to each node. Part of the logic is in main()'s for loop that advances the returned pointer to the right before calling the traversal function again (an alternative would be to have a helper function that advances to the right and then calls the main traversal function):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* binary tree node */
typedef struct BTNODE_
{
    struct BTNODE_* left;
    struct BTNODE_* right;
    int data;
}BTNODE;

/* traverse binary tree without stack */
/* initial input parameter is pointer to root */
/* predecessor of cur is largest value < cur */
/* predecessor of cur = cur->left->right->right->right ... */
BTNODE * MorrisTraversal(BTNODE *cur)
{
BTNODE *pre;
    if(cur == NULL)
        return(NULL);
    while(cur != NULL){
        /* if left end of branch, return */
        if(cur->left == NULL)
            return(cur);
        /* advance pre to predecessor of cur */
        pre = cur->left;
        while(pre->right != NULL && pre->right != cur)
            pre = pre->right;
        /* if right end of branch, change pre->right = cur */
        /*  and advance cur left */
        if(pre->right == NULL){
            pre->right = cur;
            cur = cur->left;
        /* else back at cur, so restore pre->right = NULL */
        /*  and return */
        } else {
            pre->right = NULL;
            return(cur);
        }
    }
    return(NULL);
}

BTNODE* newbtNode(int data)
{
BTNODE* btNode = (BTNODE*) malloc(sizeof(BTNODE));
    btNode->left = NULL;
    btNode->right = NULL;
    btNode->data = data;
    return(btNode);
}

int main()
{
BTNODE *cur;
/* create a 15 element binary tree */
BTNODE *root = newbtNode(8);
    root->left                = newbtNode( 4);
    root->left->left          = newbtNode( 2);
    root->left->left->left    = newbtNode( 1);
    root->left->left->right   = newbtNode( 3);
    root->left->right         = newbtNode( 6);
    root->left->right->left   = newbtNode( 5);
    root->left->right->right  = newbtNode( 7);
    root->right               = newbtNode(12);
    root->right->left         = newbtNode(10);
    root->right->left->left   = newbtNode( 9);
    root->right->left->right  = newbtNode(11);
    root->right->right        = newbtNode(14);
    root->right->right->left  = newbtNode(13);
    root->right->right->right = newbtNode(15);
    for(cur = root; cur; cur = cur->right){
        cur = MorrisTraversal(cur);
        printf("%2d ", cur->data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this works for arrays. What about the BST case?

Comment: @fluter - I updated my answer to include the BST case.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there are 3 loops the overall operation count grows linearly with the number of input items. This is O(n). While the first while doesn't increment in a predictable way like the other two, it does not change O(n). This is basically a merge operation. During the merge process, any duplicates will be detected. This will involve only one pass per list, and will terminate as soon as the end of either list is reached.

```js
function mergetwosorted(a, b) {

  var c = new Array(a.length + b.length),
    ai = 0,
    bi = 0,
    ci = 0;


  while (ai < a.length && bi < b.length) {

    if (a[ai] < b[bi]) {
      c[ci] = a[ai];
      ai++;
    } else {
      c[ci] = b[bi]
      bi++;
    }
    ci++;
  }

  while (ai < a.length) {
    c[ci] = a[ai];
    ai++
    ci++
  }
  while (bi < b.length) {
    c[ci] = b[bi];
    ci++;
    bi++;
  }
  return c;

}


console.log(mergetwosorted([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Start at beginning of both the arrays.

arr[0], arr1[0]

If arr[0] > arr1[0], binary search for position in arr1 that is equal to or greater than arr1. Then you have a sub problem of similar type arr[1..n], arr[k..m] where k is the index that was found in the binary search phase.

Comment: Binary search is actually *less* efficient than linear search in this case, because the linear search is amortized constant time whereas the binary search is still logarithmic time.

Comment: I know.. Another way to solve it which I felt was interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look at std::set_difference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection

I tried with set which is usually implemented using binary search tree and it works.

```
set<int> s1 = {1, 2, 4, 5};
set<int> s2 = {0, 2, 4, 7};
vector<int> v;
set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(),
                 s2.begin(), s2.end(),
                 back_inserter(v));
for (auto i : v)
    cout << i << '\n';
```

Output

```
2
4
```

Here is a recursive idea for the problem
For any array A with length n, I will use A[2 .. n] to indicate array [A[2], ..., A[n]]

Let A, B be the two input arrays with length n, m.
If either is empty, the answer is trivial.

Otherwise, lets compare the first entry.

If A[0] == B[0], then we know A[0] appear in both array, we store A[0] to output list and continue our search for arrays A[2 .. n] and B[2 .. m]

If A[0] < B[0], then we know A{0] will not appear in both array as every elements in B is at least B[0]. So we continue our search for arrays A[2 .. n] and B.

Similarly if A[0] > B[0], we continue our search for arrays A and B[2 .. n]

Then with recursion you can find the answer. And why does it works for binary search tree? It is because we only need an increasing sequence for each input. And we can get such sequence by in order traversal on the tree.